# I want to render some html elements which I get from my webserver in with LitElement

Tags: javascript, lit-element

I want to get some HTML elments from a webserver and render them in my web component with LitElement. My elements are saved as Strings in a MongoDB, an element is for example `<div> do something</div>`.

I already get the elements with XMLHttpRequest but can not assign them to my property and render them.

```
import { LitElement, html } from 'lit-element';
class CassKomponent extends LitElement {
  static get properties() {
    return {
      url: { type: String },
      myArray: { type: Array },
    };
  }
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.url = 'url';
    this.myArray = [];
    this.getResource;
  }
  render() {
    return html`
      <div id="check"></div>
      <div>${this.url}</div>
      <ul>
        ${this.myArray.map((i) => html`<li>${i}</li>`)}
      </ul>
    `;
  }

  getResource() {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open('GET', this.url, true);
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var response = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        console.log(response);
        //tried this one and it doesn't work
        //document.querySelector('.heck').innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
        this.myArray = response;
      }
    };
    xhttp.send();
  }
}

customElements.define('cass-komponent', CassKomponent);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had changed it to fetch and it works somehow, tho  I have no explanation for it. so my final solution looks like this.

```
render() {
    return html `
        <div id='placeholder'> </div>
    `;
}

async getResource() {
    fetch(this.url)
        .then((response) => response.text())
        .then((responseText) => {
            this.myArray = JSON.parse(responseText);
            this.shadowRoot.getElementById('placeholder').innerHTML = this.myArray;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            alert("The data could not be fetched");
            console.error(error);
        });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**

I had misunderstood where the problem was, I missed it was in the network requesting part.

If possible, I would suggests using `fetch()` instead `XMLHttpRequest()`, as it would make things easier to write... and easier to debug. What would you think :

```js
async getResource() {
  let response = await fetch(this.url);
  let jsonResponse = await response.json();
  console.log(jsonResponse);
  this.myArray =jsonResponse;
}
```

More info on `fetch()` on [MDN site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

---

If you want render an HTML element (and you're sure it's safe), you can use the [`unsafehtml` directive](https://lit-html.polymer-project.org/guide/template-reference#unsafehtml) from lit-html in your rendering.

In your rendering, you could use:

```js
  render() {
    return html`
      <div id="check"></div>
      <div>${this.url}</div>
      <ul>
        ${this.myArray.map((i) => html`<li>${unsafeHTML(i)}</li>`)}
      </ul>
    `;
  }
```

Would it be a solution in your case?

Comment: nope, the problem is rather that myArray is not recognized in the getResource() method

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood where the problem was then... A naive question, why are you using `XMLHttpRequest`? Could you use a `fetch()`? It would make the network requesting simpler...

Comment: I have had changed it to fetch and it works somehow, tho  I have no explanation for it. so my final solution looks like this.